# Limiting variables in Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, jquery-animate, action

I am creating a game for my Scripting and Interactive Web module at university, and it is not my strong suite.

I currently have a pirate ship, with the coding to make it move left and right, and speed up and slow down, however, I don't know how to limit the speed up and slow down values.

At the moment, the ship can move infinitely faster both forwards and in reverse. Advice on how to stop this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
stage.focus = stage;
//controlling victory
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , victoryController);
function victoryController(evt:KeyboardEvent){
    var aPress=String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode);
    if (aPress=="a"){victory.rotation-=1;}
    if (aPress=="d"){victory.rotation+=1;}
    if (aPress=="w"){victorySpeed+=0.5;}
    if (aPress=="s"){victorySpeed-=0.5;}
    if (aPress=="A"){victory.rotation-=1;}
    if (aPress=="D"){victory.rotation+=1;}
    if (aPress=="W"){victorySpeed+=0.5;}
    if (aPress=="S"){victorySpeed-=0.5;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if for the speed, you did something like

```
var MaxVictorySpeed = 100;

// ...

if ((aPress=="w") && (victorySpeed < MaxVictorySpeed)){
    victorySpeed+=0.5;
}
```

And so on, before setting the new value, you can check if it will be out of the intended range.

Comment: Worked an absolute charm! Thank you for the hasty response, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome. :) Note that in your game this may not be very important, but in this example `MaxVictorySpeed` may be misleading. Depending on the increment (now 0.5), the max value (now 100) and the initial value (0 I suppose) the actual reachable value may be more than thr max. In an extreme case, consider setting max to 37 and the increment to for example 9. The values would go like 9, 18, 27, 36, which ia still less than 37, so it would be possible to reach 45. Just wanted to note this to be more precise. :) You could look at the already incremented value in the if to overcome this. :)